# Save multiple images onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, canvas, html5-canvas

We are displaying Two mask images in page.

[image]

Once User click on  Mask images,  we are displaying File upload dialog box, so that user will upload their own image and click on save button.

[image]

Once user click on "save" button, we are saving those images in server....

**Issue** :

Only **latest uploaded image** is saving in server....

**Example** : User upload car to Mask1 - > User upload bike to Mask2 - > Click save - > Only Bike image save in server....

**Requirement** :

We need to save both the uploaded images in server. Means Both Bike & Car image need to be saved....

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/rXaKar) , [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/dfb4n8pu/2/) & [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/5LX95ssk)

```js
var target;
const imageUrl = "";

var jsonData  = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 600,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 160,
            "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
            "y": 281,
            "height": 296,
            "width": 429,
            "name": "mask_1"
        }, {
            "x": 25,
            "src": "hEM2kEP.png",
            "height": 324,
            "width": 471,
            "y": 9,
            "name": "mask_2"
        }],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;
let file;

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part 
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        console.log(layer1);
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            var ImagePosition = arr;

            var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1 ? imageUrl1 : undefined,

                // Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });

            ImagePosition.map(function(cur, index) {
                var available = cur.name.includes('mask_');

                if (!available) {
                    $('.masked-img' + index).css('pointer-events', 'none');
                }
            });

            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {
                file = fileup.files[0];
                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                //document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";                
            };
            counter++;
        }

        return mask;
    }

    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// Image code

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        const settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0,
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl, true)
            container.drawMask()
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas            
            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            scale = settings.scale,
            div;

        container.drawMask = function() {
            if (!settings.maskImage) return true;
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling
            if (settings.maskImage)
                context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage
                    .height);
            context.restore()
        };

        container.drawImage = function() {
            const img = settings.image

            settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
            settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            context.save();
            context.translate(settings.x + img.width / 2, settings.y + img.height / 2);
            context.rotate(settings.rotate);
            context.scale(settings.scale, settings.scale);
            context.translate(-(settings.x + img.width / 2), -(settings.y + img.height / 2));
            let width = img.width,
                height = img.height;
            if (img)
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, width, height);
            context.restore();
            initImage = false;
        }

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl, isMask) {
            if (!imageUrl) return true;
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            settings.scale = 1;
            settings.rotate = 0;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            initImage = true;
            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED
            if (!isMask)
                container.data('image_set' + settings.id, true)
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            // console.log('loading mask image from', imageUrl, from)
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
        };

        if (settings.maskImageUrl) {
            container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        }
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
        // ends
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));

//Download image to server 

function test() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("1");
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // THE BASE 64 DATA
    var dataFileName = document.getElementById('fileup').value.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, ''); // GET THE FILE NAME THAT USER CHOSE
    var dataFileType = dataFileName.split('.').pop();
    data = new FormData();
    data.append('imgBase64', file, file.name);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data
    }).done(function(o) {
        var response = JSON.parse(o);
        $('body').prepend('<img src="test/multiple/' + response.data[0].fileName + '" style="height: 200px; width: auto;">');
    });
}
```

```css
.save {
    font-size:20px;
} 
 
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:block; position:relative; top : 1000px; ">
<div id="container" class="container">
</div>
    
<button class ="save" onclick="test()">Save image to server</button>
```

**Save.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['imgBase64'])) {

    $fname   = $_FILES["imgBase64"]["name"]; // THE FILENAME THE USER CHOSE IS RECEIVED VIA POST
    $img     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgBase64'); // THE BASE64 ENCODING RECEIVED VIA POST
    $imgtype = $_FILES["imgBase64"]["type"]; // THE FILE TYPE / EXTENSION IS RECEIVED VIA POST   

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgBase64"]["tmp_name"], "test/multiple/".$fname)){
        echo '{"error":false, "message":null,"data":[{"msg": "Image has been saved successfully!", "fileName": "' . $fname . '"}]}';        
    }
    else{
        echo '{"error":true, "message":"File not uploaded"}';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: $_FILES[] is an array if there are more than 1 file uploaded in the file element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PHP Code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$number_of_images = 2; // SET THIS FOR SAID PAGE (This will control how man images that are posted will be saved!)
$json_response = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_images; $i++){
    if (isset($_FILES['imgBase64_'.$i])) {
        $fname   = $_FILES["imgBase64_".$i]["name"]; // THE FILENAME THE USER CHOSE IS RECEIVED VIA POST
        $img     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgBase64_'.$i); // THE BASE64 ENCODING RECEIVED VIA POST
        $imgtype = $_FILES["imgBase64_".$i]["type"]; // THE FILE TYPE / EXTENSION IS RECEIVED VIA POST   
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgBase64_".$i]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/html/ecom1/site/test/multiple/".$fname)){
            $json_response[] = array(
                    "error"=>'false', 
                    "message"=> 'null', 
                    "data"=> array(
                        "msg"=> "Image has been saved successfully!",
                        "fileName"=> $fname 
                    )
                );        
            }
        else{
            $json_response[] = array("error"=>"true", "message"=>"File not uploaded");
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($json_response);
?>
```

### HTML, JS and CSS

```
<style>

.save {
font-size:20px;
} 

.container {
    background: silver;
    position: relative;
}

.container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 250px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" multiple="true" style="display:block; position:relative; top : 1000px; ">
<div id="container" class="container">
</div>

<button class ="save" onclick="test()">Save image to server</button>
<script>

var target;
const imageUrl = "";

var jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 600,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 160,
            "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
            "y": 281,
            "height": 296,
            "width": 429,
            "name": "mask_1"
        }, {
            "x": 25,
            "src": "hEM2kEP.png",
            "height": 324,
            "width": 471,
            "y": 9,
            "name": "mask_2"
        }],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;
let files = [];

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part 
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        console.log(layer1);
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            var ImagePosition = arr;

            var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1 ? imageUrl1 : undefined,

                // Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });

            ImagePosition.map(function(cur, index) {
                var available = cur.name.includes('mask_');

                if (!available) {
                    $('.masked-img' + index).css('pointer-events', 'none');
                }
            });

            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {
                files.push(fileup.files[0]);
                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                //document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";                
            };
            counter++;
        }

        return mask;
    }

    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// Image code

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        const settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0,
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl, true)
            container.drawMask()
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas            
            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            scale = settings.scale,
            div;

        container.drawMask = function() {
            if (!settings.maskImage) return true;
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling
            if (settings.maskImage)
                context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage
                    .height);
            context.restore()
        };

        container.drawImage = function() {
            const img = settings.image

            settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
            settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            context.save();
            context.translate(settings.x + img.width / 2, settings.y + img.height / 2);
            context.rotate(settings.rotate);
            context.scale(settings.scale, settings.scale);
            context.translate(-(settings.x + img.width / 2), -(settings.y + img.height / 2));
            let width = img.width,
                height = img.height;
            if (img)
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, width, height);
            context.restore();
            initImage = false;
        }

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl, isMask) {
            if (!imageUrl) return true;
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            settings.scale = 1;
            settings.rotate = 0;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            initImage = true;
            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED
            if (!isMask)
                container.data('image_set' + settings.id, true)
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            // console.log('loading mask image from', imageUrl, from)
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
        };

        if (settings.maskImageUrl) {
            container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        }
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
        // ends
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));

//Download image to server 

function test() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("1");
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // THE BASE 64 DATA
    var dataFileName = document.getElementById('fileup').value.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, ''); // GET THE FILE NAME THAT USER CHOSE
    var dataFileType = dataFileName.split('.').pop();
    data = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        data.append('imgBase64_'+i, files[i], files[i].name);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data
    }).done(function(o) {
        if (o != null && o != {} && o != "") { //NULL CHECK
            var response = JSON.parse(o);
            $('body').prepend('<img src="/ecom1/site/test/multiple/' + response[0].data.fileName + '" style="height: 200px; width: auto;">'); //Loads First Image
            $('body').prepend('<img src="/ecom1/site/test/multiple/' + response[1].data.fileName + '" style="height: 200px; width: auto;">'); //Loads Second Image
        } else {
            $('body').prepend('<div>ERROR: Response Is Empty</div>');
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: so here is the new version, tested and it works 100% please try on server when you can again. cheers

Comment: Thanks, updated the above code, it gave console error  : https://i.imgur.com/zhROp3b.png

Comment: please see chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196930/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-dean-van-greunen

Answer (score 1):

This will append all files and allow it to be posted to the server.

#### PHP Notice

uploading of each image will now load each image into its own imgBase64 entry.

from this:

```
$_FILES['imgBase64']
```

will now be this: where 0 -> 2 is 0 -> N images/files.

```
$_FILES['imgBase64_0']

$_FILES['imgBase64_1']

$_FILES['imgBase64_2']
```

#### Update The HTML

```
    <!-- Add The Multiple Attribute to this input element -->
    <input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" multiple="true" style="display:block; position:relative; top : 1000px; ">
```

#### Update The Beginning Javascript to have a file array, (now files)

```
        /* ... CODE HERE ... */
        const fileUp = $('#fileup');
        let mask;
        let files = []; //Changed From 'file' to 'files' and set to an array.
        /* ... CODE HERE ... */
```

#### Update The OnChange Event for the fileup.

```
         fileup.onchange = function() {
              /////////////////////////////////////
              // Here we will push the newly added file to the list, as i hope the order that they are uploading doesn't matter.
              /////////////////////////////////////
              files.push(fileup.files[0]);   // <- This line
              let mask2 = table[target];
              const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
         };
```

#### Update the `test()` function

```
        /* ... CODE HERE ... */
        function test() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("1");
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // THE BASE 64 DATA
            var dataFileName = document.getElementById('fileup').value.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, ''); // GET THE FILE NAME THAT USER CHOSE
            var dataFileType = dataFileName.split('.').pop();
            data = new FormData();
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            // Changes Below: Loop Through the 'files' list and append to the data
            // This will attach all files.
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                data.append('imgBase64_' + i.toString();, files[i], files[i].name);
            }
            //////////////////////////////////////////          
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "save.php",
                cache:false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data
            }).done(function(o) {
                var response = JSON.parse(o);
                $('body').prepend('<img src="test/multiple/' + response.data[0].fileName + '" style="height: 200px; width: auto;">');
            });
        }
        /* ... CODE HERE ... */
```

#### Console Logging `files` before doing the ajax request, it will list the files.

[image: Console Logging]

Comment: 3 changes required to HTML and JS

Comment: sorry, did't checked  properly before as i am currently working on some bug as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158431/merge-two-buttons-to-save-two-images)

Comment: i checked properly now, i followed your code , but i am getting console error as here : https://i.imgur.com/BFlThAI.png , here is [link](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/multiple/multiple.html) , if you have full code, can you please send me , here is my code : html  : https://pastebin.com/AwzW2um1 , php : https://pastebin.com/adY30CwH

Comment: you getting that error because of the response from the php code. the returned json is not right

Comment: you getting the error because your php code is returning line 16 of https://pastebin.com/adY30CwH and not line 13, meaning that their is no data field

Comment: you can use this site to verify that your json data is correct, http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: also note that you may need to properly encode the file name, it might be breaking your json repsonse.

Comment: thanks for reply,  i checked here : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ , json data i am using is correct.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196930/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-dean-van-greunen).